# Sharing state from parent between siblings in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to have a `ScrollView` that has pages in it with navigation buttons below, like shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxdUc.jpg).

I have the following views.

```
PageNav(titles: Array<String>, views: Array<AnyView>)
PageNavTop(views: Array<AnyView>)
PageNavBottom(titles: Array<String>)
PageNavButton(title: String, action: () -> Void)
```

And I have the following `View` hierarchy, assuming I have two pages.

```
PageNav -> PageNavTop    -> AnyView<page view 1>
                         -> AnyView<page view 2>
        -> PageNavBottom -> PageNavButton(page title 1)
                         -> PageNavButton(page title 2)
```

Where `PageNavTop` has gestures attached to a scroll view so we can swipe between pages and `PageNavBottom` lets us navigate using the buttons.

The PageNav should hold a `@State var` that I will use as `@Binding var` in the child view. However, I am using a custom `init` function and I cannot seem to figure out how to pass the state to two levels down to the buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, I was almost there.

```
struct PageNav: View {
    @State var activeIndex = 0
    ...
        PageNavTop(views: self.views, activeIndex: self.$activeIndex)
        PageNavBottom(titles: self.titles, activeIndex: self.$activeIndex)
    ...
```

Notice the **underscore** in `self._activeIndex`, that's where I went wrong with using a `$`. I first tried to use `@Binding var activeIndex: Binding<Int>`, but of course I could not use the value then.

```
struct PageNavBottom: View {
    @Binding var activeIndex: Int
    ...
        PageNavButton(
            title: title,
            action: { self.activeIndex = index }
        )
    ...
    init(titles: [String], activeIndex: Binding<Int>) {
        self._activeIndex = activeIndex
```